# How to add a new field to Custom Options

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, adminhtml, custom-options, install-script

How can I extend the "Custom Options" in a configurable product? I need to add a new field named `Identifier`. Where can I find the necessary templates?

[image: Custom Field in Backend]

I figured out that the template is in `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml`, and I added my custom code to it:

[image]

But I have no clue to which table I have to add the new attribute "identifier" ?

How can I figure this out?

I thought I have to add it to the table `Catalog_Product_Edit_Options_Option` because the template is in *app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml* but this threw an error that the table could not be found.

How do I know the right table name where the attribute belongs to?

I tried to install it to the table `catalog_product_option_type_value` with this install script but it is not the right table, because if I enter something and save something then it is not saved:

```
<?php

Mage::log("Add attribute 'identifier' to table 'catalog_product_edit_options_option'", 7, "system.log");

$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('catalog_product_option_type_value'),
        'identifier',
        array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'input' => 'text',
            'nullable' => true,
            'default' => null,
            'comment' => 'Identifier of the Option, used to perform specific actions in scripts only on options with certain identifiers.'
        )
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

I also added it to the table `catalog_product_option` but it still does not save.

**Update:**
I noticed that the value is actually stored into the database, but magento fails to load it in the backend so it looks like it is empty. I used this query

```
SELECT * FROM `magecatalog_product_option` WHERE `option_id` = 443`
```

[image]

Why does it not show in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more than half the way done :-)

You have to overwrite the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option` also and add your new column `identifier` in the method `getOptionValues()`.

Add `$value['identifier'] = $option->getIdentifier();` for example after `$value['sort_order'] = $option->getSortOrder();` and with that you should have the data in the backend

Comment: Thx!! You saved my day :) Note: You should first search for classes which extends the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option` to figure out if there are already overrides. I had a overwrite in one of my extensions in `app/code/local`. Never edit core files!

Comment: I didn't say 'change code in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option', but 'overwrite the block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option' which means for me to create your own block extending that block. Sorry if the answer can be misunderstood.

Comment: Yes I know, I just added the note in case someone does not know it